# deploy c дополнительным подключением к бд

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Определил в /config/database.yml дополнительное подключение к другой базе **data**:

```
production:
  <<: *default
  database: ***
data:
 adapter: mysql2
 encoding: utf8
 pool: 5
 username: ***
 password: ***
 host: ***
 database: ***
```

Но при выполнении cap production deploy - передаются только настройки для production окружения.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как передавать еще одно подключение?
Что-то никак не приходит в голову и нагуглить не получается...

Спасибо!

Comment: А чего вы хотите добиться? Зачем вам сразу две базы в проде?

Comment: Василиса, в проекте есть несколько моделей, которые работают с удаленной базой с большим объемом данных. Локальная база используется для маленьких таблиц, таких как пользователи, миграции..

Comment: Ни разу с таким не сталкивалась, но вот есть гем для таких ситуаций https://github.com/ankane/multiverse

Comment: Для начала найдите кусок кода, который отвечает за передачу конфига. От этого и следует двигаться дальше.